# Scroll to cursor on click

Tags: javascript, web

I'm trying to get the page to smooth scroll so that the cursor is centered vertically once the left mouse button is clicked.

I know how to use an event listener to capture the click location, I'm just unsure of how to calculate the scroll offset to properly center the cursor regardless of the size and position of the scrollbar.

Comment: `Element.scrollTop` ? From the [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop)

Comment: Yes but how do I calculate the offset for the click position so that it centers?

Comment: I'm unsure what you are asking. You want to center the mouse when the user clicks to be in between the place where they clicked and the scroll bar? Or do you want the scroll bar to scroll to the position where the mouse was clicked?

Comment: I want the scroll bar to scroll to the position where the mouse was clicked =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this can work:

ES6: `document.onclick = (e) => window.scroll(0,(e.pageY-window.innerHeight/2))`

ES5: `document.onclick = function(e) { window.scroll(0,(e.pageY-window.innerHeight/2)) }`

`pageY` should represent the position of the click on the overall page.

We then use `window.innerHeight / 2` to get to the middle of the page.

When it comes to smooth scrolling, something like this might work, though I'd probably prefer to use some existing npm package to do that.

```
function smoothScroll(y, existing) {
    if(!existing && smoothScroll.active) return
    smoothScroll.active = true
    var initialScrollY = window.scrollY
    var scrollDistance = y - window.scrollY
    var scrollAmount = scrollDistance/20
    window.scroll(0, window.scrollY + scrollAmount)
    if(window.scrollY === initialScrollY) {
        smoothScroll.active = false
        return
    }
    setTimeout(function() { smoothScroll(y, true) }, 1)
}

document.onclick = function(e) { 
    smoothScroll(e.pageY-window.innerHeight/2) 
}
```

Comment: That works perfectly! You're a lifesaver, thank you!